# Referencing using Texmaker

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to make a bibliography in texmaker and it won't work at all. I've followed the exact video we were provided and it still won't work. I am just trying to get one reference to work and all I get is [?] and the bibliography wont appear. I am using these packages

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
and then at the end \bibliography{source} which is the name of my bib file

Comment: you have not given many clues. texmaker is just the editor you use to write the files, have you run pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex twice more?  latex never reads the bib file, you need bibtex to generate the bibliography

Comment: yes I have I have a bibtex file with one thing in it to test it and it seems to not find it despite me running it the correct way (the way to stated)

Comment: the question is not if you have a bibtex file the question is have you run bibtex to read it (tex never reads bib files so if you just have a bib file and never run bibtex then it will never be used)

Comment: note you have tagged biblatex but you are not using biblatex you are (oir should be) using bibtex,